# What is the effect of "chown nobody:nogroup"?

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, chown

What is the effect of `chown nobody:nogroup` on a single file or directory and what is the effect on files within a directory?

Answer (score 6):

[`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) is used to change the ownership of files and folders.

Your command just changes the owner user and group to nobody and nogroup. Both of these entities are normal objects within the system.

You can verify this by running `cat /etc/group | grep nogroup` and `cat /etc/passwd | grep nobody` respectively.

It probably doesn't make a lot of sense without also using [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) to change the actual permissions.